# Implementing a user level access in my site?

Tags: php, mysql, show-hide

I need to know how can I implement a user level access in my site. I need to hide forms and images when users with level are member...
in my DB I have a USERS TABLE with:

- id
- nombre
- apellido
- username
- password
- level

level is ENUM and have this two selects: administrator and member

I can hide scripts in any page with this type of PHP code:

```
<?php if(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == 'contact.php') { ?>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<?php } ?>
```

and works very well, but I don't know how can hide per example this:

```
<div class="box span6">
    <div class="box-header well" data-original-title>
        <h2><i class="icon-picture"></i> <?php $translate->__('Save images'); ?></h2>
        <div class="box-icon">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-minimize btn-round"><i class="icon-chevron-up"></i></a>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-close btn-round"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-content">
        <form action="upload.php" method="post" name="image_upload" id="image_upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <label><?php $translate->__('Images type'); ?> (gif, jpg, png)</label><br />
            <input type="file" size="45" name="uploadfile" id="uploadfile" class="file margin_5_0" onchange="ajaxUpload(this.form);" />
            <div id="upload_area" class="corners align_center">
                <?php $translate->__('Please select one image'); ?>.
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

In google I saw this code but don't work in my partycular case:

```
<?php if($USERS->level == "administrator"): ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

can you help me with my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Hiding js files will not do you much good because an attacker can intercept the javascript file being served to your admin user, build his own mock-up page of your site and have it use that javascript. So make sure to put security and validation in your php code, especially inside your upload.php

Obviously this $USERS->level can be replaced by any variable that you have set.

```
 <?php if($USERS->level == "administrator") 
 { 
 ?>
 <div class="box span6">
     <div class="box-header well" data-original-title>
         <h2><i class="icon-picture"></i> <?php $translate->__('Save images'); ?></h2>
         <div class="box-icon">
             <a href="#" class="btn btn-minimize btn-round"><i class="icon-chevron-up"></i></a>
             <a href="#" class="btn btn-close btn-round"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a>
         </div>
     </div>
     <div class="box-content">
         <form action="upload.php" method="post" name="image_upload" id="image_upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
             <label><?php $translate->__('Images type'); ?> (gif, jpg, png)</label><br />
             <input type="file" size="45" name="uploadfile" id="uploadfile" class="file margin_5_0" onchange="ajaxUpload(this.form);" />
             <div id="upload_area" class="corners align_center">
                 <?php $translate->__('Please select one image'); ?>.
             </div>
         </form>
     </div>
 </div>

 <?php 
 } 
 ?>
```

Comment: yes, but imagine, for instance, someone at an ISP looking through logs and seeing that someone went to yoursite.com/upload.php, or someone just guessing that you might have an upload.php, and he figures out how to upload to your server using it because you only hid the form on a different page but put no security in upload.php itself

Comment: I think I don't explain me(sorry, my english is deadly..) I put your suggestion code and with your code the form is hide for members and for administrators..I know that you warning me about the possibility to any member can overpass the javascript level access...right now my code is only for use to lawyers and the hide is for the staff in the firm..like secretaries and another type of employees.. and the hide will be only for per example the monthly income and the consultation for every client